# Using apply/sapply on a user defined function with multiple parameters

Tags: r, apply, sapply

For a university project I am programming a decision tree algorithm. To do so I wrote a function for numeric variables that determines the best split. This function works properly when I give it input variables. The selection of the split is based on the gini index.

```
gini.index <- function(input){
  l <- length(input)
  som <- sum(input)
  probability <- 1 - som/l
  gini <- probability * (1-probability)
  gini
}

impurity.reduction <- function(y, yl,yr){
  pi.l <- length(yl)/length(y)
  pi.r <- length(yr)/length(y)
  imp.red <- gini.index(y) - (pi.l * gini.index(yl) + pi.r * gini.index(yr))
  imp.red
}

best.split.point <- function(x,y){
  if (length(x) == length(y)){

    #bekijk mogelijke numerieke waarden om op te splitten
    x.sorted <- sort(unique(x))
    x.sorted.length <- length(x.sorted)
    splitpoints <- (x.sorted[1:(x.sorted.length-1)]+x.sorted[2:x.sorted.length])/2
    splitpoints

    #creer een lege vector om in de for loop alle impurity reduction waarden per split op te kunnen slaan
    puur <- vector()

    #bekijk voor ieder splitpoint wat de impurity reduction is
    for (i in 1:length(splitpoints)) {
      y1 <- y[x < splitpoints[i]]
      y2 <- y[x >= splitpoints[i]]
      puur <- c(puur,impurity.reduction(y,y1,y2))

    }
    splitpoints[puur == max(puur)]
  }
  else {
    return("Variables X & Y need to be of the same length")
  }
}
```

When I try the following command to find out what the best feature split is for every separate column in my dataset I get the following error:

```
sapply(credit.dat, best.split.point(credit.dat, y))
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'Variables X & Y need to be of the same length' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Some other posts suggests that it could be due to the naming of my function (which I already changed). I think the error has to do something with the composition of my function probably. Could one of you please help me finding out what makes this error pop up?

The credit dataset is available here: http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/mdm/credit.txt
The y variable is the sixth column of the credit dataset, so:

```
credit.dat <- read.csv("http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/mdm/credit.txt")
y <- credit.dat[, 6]
```

Comment: example for `sapply()`: `sapply(iris[-5], FUN=mean)` (**not** *FUN=mean(...)*) But this is not the only error. What object is `credit.dat`? Is it a dataframe? If yes, then `sapply()` is working over the columns of it (one by one).

Comment: So what would be the solution for multiple input parameters for the function in the FUN part of `apply()`? `best.split.point` requires two arguments. `credit.dat` is a dataframe. Good to hear that it should work over the columns one by one! That's what it is supposed to do. The credit dataset is available in the link in the original post. @jogo

Comment: passing additional parameters to `sapply` can be handled using `...`, look at this post here for an example https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works:

```
credit.dat <- read.csv("http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/mdm/credit.txt")
y <- credit.dat[, 6]

sapply(credit.dat, FUN=best.split.point, y=y)
# > sapply(credit.dat, best.split.point, y=y)
#     age married   house  income  gender   class 
#    32.5     0.5     0.5    36.0     0.5     0.5
```